# php readonly function parameter

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

```
$variable = ...;
$result=exampleFunction($variable);

exampleFunction(readonly $variable)
{
    ...
}
```

I mean I want to make read only parameter in function,
Is possible to do this in PHP?

Comment: The param will not be modified when you call a function unless you have `&$variable`, just remove readonly and it's all

Comment: No. But you can just decide not to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments *are* read-only (with the exception of objects and resources). So, there is no reason for a `readonly` keyword.

For objects you can use the `clone` keyword when you pass the argument into the function. For example:

```
exampleFunction(clone $obj);
```

Resources must be created as read-only, if you want them to be only read-only.